# Fetch random article from Wikipedia api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, wikipedia-api

I want to display the words

```
From _________ to __________
```

on my website, where ***_*__** stands for a random Wikipedia article.

I think I need to use the Wikipedia API but how do I incorporate it into my Rails app?

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in how to fetch a random article from the API, the best way would be the following API call:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=random&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=1

This call returns one random article from the English Wikipedia. You can try this out in the [API sandbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=query&format=json&list=random&rnnamespace=0&rnlimit=1).

Answer (score 0):

You could start by using the wikipedia client gem.

You can find it here https://github.com/kenpratt/wikipedia-client

Comment: There's a command called wikipedia.find(....) but you need to have a title of a wikipedia article in the command. I just want a random article.

Comment: I wonder if that could work if there’s a way to access (or create) a text file of the titles of all articles and save them to “articles”. Then Wikipedia.find(random_article) —- where random_article grabs a random article from that list.